# SSH Error: ssh_exchange_identification

Tags: ssh

While doing ssh on mac i am getting following error. Can anyone please explain what is this issue

```
dlopen /usr/lib/kr-pkcs11.so failed: dlopen(/usr/lib/kr-pkcs11.so, 2): image not found
zsh:1: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/krssh
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-ssh/

Comment: 1) Post the verbose log from the connection (`-vvv` switches). 2) What do you have in your `~/.ssh/config` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I fixed this issue. The issue was with invalid path. Check this issue
https://github.com/KryptCo/kr/issues/82#issuecomment-298876415